# Careers 2.0 doesn't have the option to log out from GitHub

Tags: support, jobs

I'm trying out Careers 2.0 and I decided to hook it up to GitHub. I quickly blasted through the OAuth without realising that I was logged in using a different GitHub account than my own (a holding account I set up for an open source project I'm involved in so people couldn't steal the account name). But I can't now seem to disassociate this account with my Careers profile nor can I attach a different GitHub account to my profile.

This seems like a problem.

Comment: Have you tried logging out of GitHub entirely, then doing the import again?

Comment: That solves the problem!

Answer (score 4):

The answer seems pretty simple: log out of GitHub and Careers, then log back into both. Thanks to Matt Sherman (comment above) for the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try logging out of Github entirely, and do the same on Careers, then log back into both. (Your Github credentials can survive for the length of your session.)