# Change github user link

Tags: bug, jobs, github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Careers 2.0 doesn't have the option to log out from GitHub](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91122/careers-2-0-doesnt-have-the-option-to-log-out-from-github)

I accidentally linked my Careers account to the wrong github username. I revoked access in github, but now I can't link my Careers account to the correct github username. Is there no way to clear that association?