# How to remove an existing GitHub link to a Careers profile?

Tags: bug, jobs, github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Careers 2.0 doesn't have the option to log out from GitHub](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91122/careers-2-0-doesnt-have-the-option-to-log-out-from-github)

So, I clicked on the "Add Github" link, but confirmed before I realized that I was logged into the wrong GitHub account. Now my Careers profile seems to be inextricably linked and I can't change it to link to the correct account. There seems to be no way to remove an existing GitHub link so I can have a re-do. Am I missing something (hopefully)? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, we do hold on to those credentials and log you in automatically when possible. We haven’t added an interface to “forget my github” yet.

As a workaround, you can “revoke” us at Github itself: https://github.com/settings/applications

Do that, and then log out of Github entirely. Then go back to Careers and click the “add Github” link again, and you will get a new login prompt, which should allow you to use the other account.